# How to change interactive scale control in plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly

I can interactively change the scale of the graph and change its position, special zones on the scales are responsible for this

```
library(plotly)
x <- 1:50
y <- cumsum(rnorm(50))
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
fig <- layout(fig, plot_bgcolor='lightgrey')
fig
```

[image]

I would like to know if I can remove the `up / down`, `left / right` controls, and in their place insert only `stretch / narrow`.

[image]